# How can I access the 1st element of a nested list?

Tags: python-3.x, list

I have a nested list and I want to pull out the first element of every list of lists:

```
t = [
          [['a',1],['b',2],['c',3]],
          [['d',1],['e',2],['f',3]],
          [['g',1],['h',2],['i',3]]
]

want = ['a','d','g']
```

I am getting the Comphrension wrong:

```
list = [x[0][0] for x in t]
```

Comment: Have you tried writing some ordinary loops and then converting them to list comprehensions one step at a time?

Comment: I was hoping for a pythonic way

Comment: Apart from naming your variable list your solution seems fine.

Comment: Why do you think your code is wrong? It's unclear what the problem is.

Comment: @ManInMoon The pythonic way is "if your comprehensions don't work, write them as ordinary loops and then convert them to comprehensions one step at a time"

Comment: @ManInMoon **loops are Pythonic**

Comment: In *any* case, what, exactly isn't working? The result of `[x[0][0] for x in t]` is `['a', 'd', 'g']`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will work as long as you don't call your variable 'list' (call it 'new_t' or whatever) - list is a reserved word in python.

Comment: list is *not* a reserved word in Python. Assigning the result of a list comprehension to the variable `list` wont in any way prevent the list comprehension from working

Comment: if you accidentally assign a value to `list` (e.g. in the command line interpreter), you can reset it with `list = type([])` or `list = [].__class__`